# What is on the handlebars of this bike?

Tags: parts, handlebars

Sadiq Khan, the current Mayor of London, was [spotted](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/54874/29011) riding a (strikingly regular) bike around in May 2020.

What is the contraption attached to the center of his handlebars?

[image: odd contraption attached to center of handlebars]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks to me like Shimano CI Deck gear indicators. They connect to the shifters with a little cable that pulls a dial to tell the rider what gear they're using.

[image]
<sup>https://si.shimano.com/pdfs/si/SI-6XJ0A-000-ENG.pdf</sup>

From the user's view:
[image]

Comment: not so regular after all ;)

Comment: These are similar in concept to the Visual Gear Display/Indicator (VGD / VGI)  on many MTB pod shifters.  I have a similar display on my alfine11 hub because otherwise there's no way to know what gear it is in.  DI2-equipped bikes can have a wireless display module peered with the system too.   Tandem riders can appreciate how hard it is to see your own cassette and chainrings when they're several metres behind you!